# Jquery Numeric Plugin is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have just downloaded jquery numeric plugin and already added jquery library too but still it's not working so if you people can take a look at my code as please :

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.numeric.js"></script>
</head>
<p>How many Questions would you like to have in your form?</p>
<form action="" method="post">
<input class="positive-integer" name="questions" placeholder="Type questions number in digits as e.g 5" style="width:19%;" type="text" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

It should have to work on the input as for `class="positive-integer"` :

```
<input class="positive-integer" name="questions" placeholder="Type questions number in digits as e.g 5" style="width:19%;" type="text" />
```

So if you people can please take a look at my code..!

Here is live link to the file as : http://www.huntedhunter.com/php-login/test/questions.php

Comment: Why don't you use [`type="number"`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html)?

Comment: Really I would like to but that doesn't fit my needs I want people to prevent from typing alphabets inside that input..! only numbers should have to be allowed to be typed in..!

Comment: which plugin you are trying?

Comment: @UmairShah Thats exactly what `type="number"` does.

Comment: I have mentioned above it's called Jquery Numeric Plugin.

Comment: @indieblue : Really I tried but I was able to type alphabets in thre really don't know if it submit that or not?

Comment: @UmairShah Thats because you are not using a HTML5 compatible browser most probably.

Comment: @indieblue : Really.I am using Google Chrome.! Is it not HTML5 Compatible?

Comment: @UmairShah Sorry, I was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i can't see this code on  view source page add this code on page.

```
$(function(){
  $('.positive-integer').numeric();
})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shE58/29/)

Comment: Yes...exactly what I was missing..I had not defined functions in there..!

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize the plugin in order to make your example work..

Include this in your page

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        $(".positive-integer").numeric()
    });
</script>
```